# Assigning static data amount in a div to be called from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an example based on the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tt7d3e6/

In this, a function is created to turn a number into words.

The function is processed in the following HTML

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" />
<div id="word"></div>
```

The above allows you to enter a number into a textbox. The function translates what you type as a number into words.

Is there an easy way to set a div which already holds the number, instead of typing it to display?'

Such as:

```
<div data="innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(1233213)"></div>
```

Comment: `onkeyup` is a event which is being invoked .. `data` is not!

Answer (score 0):

You can hookup an event handler for `onreadystatechange` and inside that you can put your logic.

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5tt7d3e6/27/)

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    word.innerHTML = convertNumberToWords(1233213);
};
```

However if you want show data based on existing value inside `input`, first put an id attribute for `input`

```
<input id="number" ... />
```

And then in JS:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    word.innerHTML = convertNumberToWords(number.value);
};
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5tt7d3e6/28/)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use switch statment in convertNumberToWords()

```
 switch(amount){
     case 0: 'zero'; break;
     default: 'Please enter number only!'; break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nzRje/180/)

change the value of textbox and press click button it will return into word

```
<input id="check"type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" />
<div id="word"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click">
```

js code

```
$("#button").click(function()
{
 var number = $('#check').val(); 
 $("#word").html(toWords(number));

});


var th = ['','thousand','million', 'billion','trillion'];
var dg = ['zero','one','two','three','four', 'five','six','seven','eight','nine']; var tn = ['ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen', 'fourteen','fifteen','sixteen', 'seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']; var tw = ['twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']; function toWords(s){s = s.toString(); s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g,''); if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number'; var x = s.indexOf('.'); if (x == -1) x = s.length; if (x > 15) return 'too big'; var n = s.split(''); var str = ''; var sk = 0; for (var i=0; i < x; i++) {if ((x-i)%3==2) {if (n[i] == '1') {str += tn[Number(n[i+1])] + ' '; i++; sk=1;} else if (n[i]!=0) {str += tw[n[i]-2] + ' ';sk=1;}} else if (n[i]!=0) {str += dg[n[i]] +' '; if ((x-i)%3==0) str += 'hundred ';sk=1;} if ((x-i)%3==1) {if (sk) str += th[(x-i-1)/3] + ' ';sk=0;}} if (x != s.length) {var y = s.length; str += 'point '; for (var i=x+1; i<y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] +' ';} return str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the document as it is processed and ***not later***.

```
<div id="word">

  <script>
    document.write(convertNumberToWords(12233456))
  </script>

</div>
```

---

This is the recommended way though:

```
<div id="word"></div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = convertNumberToWords(12233456);
  </script>
```

--

```html
<script>
  function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
      var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var received_n_array = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
        received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
      }
      for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
        n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
      }
      for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
          if (n_array[i] == 1) {
            n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
            n_array[i] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      value = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
          value = n_array[i] * 10;
        } else {
          value = n_array[i];
        }
        if (value != 0) {
          words_string += words[value] + " ";
        }
        if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Crores ";
        }
        if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Lakhs ";
        }
        if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Thousand ";
        }
        if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
          words_string += "Hundred and ";
        } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
          words_string += "Hundred ";
        }
      }
      words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
  }
</script>
<div id="word">

  <script>
    document.write(convertNumberToWords(12233456))
  </script>

</div>
```